# Characteristic functions and convergence of complex sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

I'm trying to solve the following question, but I have no idea why the hint was given as it was:

[image]

---

**My attempt:** I'm not really able to make use of the hint so far, so I'm a bit lost:

The assumptions give that $e^{i t x_n} \rightarrow c(t) + i s(t) \equiv z(t)$ for some real functions $s(t), c(t)$ with $\cos(x_n t) \rightarrow c(t)$, $\sin(x_n t) \rightarrow s(t)$.

$z(t)$ cannot be zero for any $t$ since $||e^{itx_n}| - |z(t)|| \leq |e^{itx_n} - z(t)|$ and $|e^{itx_n}| = 1$ so that $|z(t)| = 1$

$$E(e^{i t x_n U}) = f(x_n) \equiv \begin{cases} \frac{e^{itx_n} - 1}{itx_n} & x_n \ne 0 \\
1 & x_n = 0 \end{cases}$$

Dominated convergence gives us that $$E(c(tU) + i s(tU)) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)$$

Unfortunately I am not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint is suggesting that the sequence of random variables $(x_nU)$ is converging in distribution to some limit $L$. If you manage to prove this, it remains to deduce that the sequence $(x_n)$ itself is converging to something. This would be trivial if $(x_n)$ were bounded, in which case you conclude that $\frac12x_n=E(x_nU)\to E(L)$. But boundedness of $(x_n)$ is not given.

Instead, try proving that the sequence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, i.e. that
$$\lim (x_{n_k}-x_{m_k}) = 0$$
for any increasing sequences $(n_k)$ and $(m_k)$. By hypothesis $$\lim_k\exp (itx_{n_k}U)=\lim_k\exp(itx_{m_k}U)$$ almost surely. Therefore the ratio
$$\exp(itx_{n_k}U) / \exp(itx_{m_k}U) = \exp it(x_{n_k}-x_{m_k})U$$
tends to $1$ almost surely. Apply dominated convergence to conclude
$$E[\exp it(x_{n_k}-x_{m_k})U]\to 1$$
for every $t$, which implies $(x_{n_k}-x_{m_k})U$ converges in distribution to the constant $0$. From here you can argue the sequence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy.

Comment: I need that the limit of $E(e^{itx_n U})$ is continuous at $t = 0$ in order to use Levy's continuity theorem to state the existence of the limiting distribution $L$ - this would hold if $c(t)$ and $s(t)$ have limits of $1$ and $0$ as $t \rightarrow 0$, and this would hold if the convergence of $e^{itx_n}$ is uniform.  Is this the case?

Comment: RIght, you need Levy's continuity theorem. To prove continuity at $0$, uniform convergence of $\exp(itx_n)$ to $z(t)$ would be sufficient, but you can't be sure of uniform convergence. Remember the limiting CF is $E[z(tU)]=\int_0^1 z(tu)du$.

Comment: The second argument you have here works without all of the uniform stuff.  I understand that $(x_{n_k} - x_{m_k})U \xrightarrow{d} 0$ so that it also converges to $0$ in probability.  Would the following argument work to say that the sequence $a_k \equiv x_{n_k} - x_{m_k} \rightarrow 0$?  If it does not converge to zero, then there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ and a subsequence $a_{k_j}$ such that $|a_{k_j}| > \epsilon$.  Thus $$P(|a_{k_j} U| > \epsilon/2) \ge  P(\epsilon U > \epsilon/2) = 1/2$$ for every $j$.  This is a contradiction since $a_{k_j} U \xrightarrow{P} 0$.

Comment: Yep, that argument will do it.